# Understaning the use of onDraw(Canvas canvas) method of View

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

Asking this question because I'm feeling confused after reading multiple Canvas related blogs and Docs.

I saw that the View class has a method -

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
}
```

My question is when you use any stock Android View like Button, TextView and EditText.

1. Is `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` called by the compiler for every stock Android View you use ?
2. How is the Canvas object supplied or who supplies the Canvas object ?
3. Is there any one Canvas in one Activity/Fragment or can there be multiple Canvas as well ?

Comment: 1. Yes (for example, `RelativeLayout` extends `ViewGroup` and `ViewGroup` draws the view 2. You supply it (when creating a custom view) 3. There can be multiple

Comment: @HB.Any UI that you see on an Android screen is just a Bitmap that holds the pixels, at the core. When you, let us suppose use a TextView on your UI to print your name, the TextView internally uses Canvas to get painting tools needed to print your name and to render the Texts painted, and output it on the Bitmap. 

Is this statement correct ?

Comment: No not all UI views/widgets are `Bitmap`s. A `TextView` for example is, AFAIK, made out of drawables, nine patch drawables to be more specific. Bitmaps are very memory heavy and would not make sense using it when not necessary. To see Android's core source code, you can Google, for example (android textview source code) you will learn a lot about how Android works at it's core, I did.